# How to add multi-language in ZK validation notice?

Tags: zk

I am use ZK 8.I know how to display ZK validation notice, but I don't know best way to display multi-language validation notice. Help me display multi-language in ZK validation notice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support multiple languages, you could use the 「l」 function as depicted in the Internationalization chapter.

```
<datebox constraint="no empty, no future: ${c:l('err.date.nowornever')}"/>
```

For complex/multiple validation rules, read reference:
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Base_Components/InputElement#Validation 
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Messages